# Why does the PureScript compiler generate lots of "| 0"

Tags: purescript

The following PureScript code:

```
fibs 0 = 1
fibs 1 = 1
fibs n = fibs (n-1) + fibs (n-2)
```

Compiles to the following JavaScript:

```
var fibs = function (v) {
    if (v === 0) {
        return 1;
    };
    if (v === 1) {
        return 1;
    };
    return fibs(v - 1 | 0) + fibs(v - 2 | 0) | 0;
};
```

Which all makes perfect sense, except the "| 0"s seem a bit unnecessary.  Is it an optimisation?  Or to make it robust to undefined or NaNs ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inserting `|0` for integers ensures that values do not accidentally become floating-point or fall out of range for int32 - this guarantees that bitwise operations will behave as expected on `Int` values too.

In theory it could be an optimisation, as asm.js sees `|0` as a hint that a value is an int too, but I think in practice that's wishful thinking that it makes a difference in the average JS program!

Comment: Interesting!  Can you give an example where this run-time behaviour would be desirable in catching a bug that wouldn't otherwise be caught by the type system at compile time?